# Coroutine and Async / Await

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio

I ran into an asyncIO problem. I want to have my program do something while a task a coroutine is being run, and after the coroutine is done, exit.

I've simplified my problem into this snippet:

```
import time
import asyncio


async def long_task():
    time.sleep(3)
    return "DONE !"


def do_while_idle():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    task = loop.create_task(long_task)
    while not task.done():
        time.sleep(1)
        print("IDLE")
    print(task.result())


do_while_idle()
```

I'd like to have this output:

```
IDLE
IDLE
IDLE
DONE !
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use time.sleep(3) in an asyncio loop. Use asyncio.sleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MisterMiyagi [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61485714/coroutine-and-async-await/61489302?noredirect=1#comment108767119_61485714), you must await `asyncio.sleep()` instead of calling `time.sleep()`, as well as eliminate other blocking, e.g. by replacing the use of `requests` with [`aiohttp`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/).

To do some idle code for as long as a task is running, you can write the idle code as an infinite loop, independent of the main task. `do_while_idle` can start the idle loop as a task, directly await `long_task()`, and then just cancel the idle one:

```
import asyncio

async def long_task():
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    return "DONE !"

async def idle():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("IDLE")

async def do_while_idle():
    idle_task = asyncio.create_task(idle())
    print(await long_task())
    idle_task.cancel()

asyncio.run(do_while_idle())
```

Comment: Exactly this! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can approach this like so:

```py
import asyncio

async def do_while_idle():
    for _ in range(3):
        print("IDLE")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

    return "Done stuff while idling"

async def long_task():
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    return "DONE !"

async def main():
    task = asyncio.create_task(long_task())
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(do_while_idle())
    done, _ = await asyncio.wait({task, task2})

    if task in done:
        task2.cancel()
        print(task.result())

asyncio.run(main())
```

Idling should be another task, this snippet waits for the long_task to be finished, and cancels the idling task. You can also check if both idling and long_task is finished like so:

```py
async def main():
    task = asyncio.create_task(long_task())
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(do_while_idle())
    done, _ = await asyncio.wait({task, task2})

    if task and task2 in done:
        print(task.result(), task2.result())
```

First code snippet will give you the result you want:

```
IDLE
IDLE
IDLE
DONE !
```

Comment: Thank you for your time.

But it is not quite what I need. I need do_while_idle() to be return/print something every one second, no matter how long "long_task" run.

Your code snippet only works because you hardcoded "3" in both coro.

Comment: @daolf You can replace `for _ in range(3)` with `while True` and it should work just as well.

Comment: I think it won't because asyncio.wait wait for all task to be finished.

Comment: @daolf Yes you can replace it with while True, because in the first code snippet, when the long_task gets completed, task2 is being cancelled

Comment: @daolf Good point. It could be fixed by using `return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED`, but it can be expressed without `wait()` at all. I've written it up as an answer.